# Is it okay for a hydraulic chain tensioner to clack? - Video

Tags: escape, timing-chain, hydraulic-pressure

2002 Ford Escape V6 400,000 miles

[image]

[**This video**](https://youtu.be/HeAxk45M8yQ) should explain what I'm trying to say. In the video the chain tensioners are in the top left and top center of the screen and you can really see what I'm talking about at the 18 second mark. **The first thud you hear is the breaker bar against the control arm (not the tensioner clack I'm talking about).*

I'm afraid then when I removed it I compressed it one too many times and that weakened it? Maybe I just squeezed all the oil out?

I'm worried that if its a little clack when I do it by hand it will be a big clack when the engine is actually running. Or is that how they are supposed to sound or will they fill back up with oil once the engine is running and get strong again?

*btw the timing cover is already back on and it was a real PITA oh and I don't want to redo the timing again so I'm really hoping you won't ask me to repair or replace these.*

Comment: Can you add information about your specific car?  Make, model, engine etc.

Comment: 2002 Ford Escape V6 400,000 miles.

Comment: btw yes it started up and ran without any problems.